# Loading images sequentially using Jquery in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine

**Solution**: 
I used setTimeout(ajaxcall,timeoutmillis) instead of making all ajax calls instantly.
The images were updated perfectly. No problem.
**Never send multiple ajax request in a loop without giving browser some time to breathe.**
:)

I am uploading multiple images to Google App Engine using javascript. I am sending images
one by one to the server and receiving responses from server one by one. The response
contains thumbnail link of the loaded image. I want to be able to display those thumbnails as they come one by one. The problem is that for example if I have 100 images the images are not displayed until 100th response is received from the server. Till then the page behaves as if it is loading something but images are not visible. All the images show up after the Ajax call is complete though.

**Update**: I have found not so elegant workaround. If you create image placeholders with
some dummy image and change the img src later during ajax load, it works. Not very elegant solution but if you add 1 pixel invisible image the effect will be more or less the same.

Here is the code.

```
this.handlephotoupload = function(input) {
    var uploadedfiles = input.files;
    var toolarge = "";
    var maxsize = 10240000;
    var counter = 1;
    var downloadcounter = 0;
    var rownumber = 0;
    var images=new Array();
    var arraycount=0;
    var totalimagecount=0;
    $("#phototable").append("<tr><td><div id=loading>Loading images please wait......</div></td></tr>");
    for(var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++) {
        if(uploadedfiles[i].size > maxsize) {
            toolarge += uploadedfiles[i].name + "\n";
            totalimagecount+=1;
        } else {
            var filedata = new FormData();
            filedata.append("uploadimage", uploadedfiles[i]);
            $("#loading").show();
            $.ajax({
                url : 'photodownloader',
                data : filedata,
                cache : false,
                contentType : false,
                processData : false,
                type : 'POST',
                success : function(receiveddata) {
                    var imagedata = JSON.parse(receiveddata);
                    var data = imagedata['imageinfo'];
                    var imagelink = data['imagelink'];
                    var thumbnaillink = data['thumbnailLink'];
                    var imageID = data['uniqueID'];
                    var imagename = data['imagename'];
                    if(downloadcounter % 3 == 0) {
                        rownumber += 1;
                        var row = $('<tr id=thumbnailsrow' + rownumber + '></tr>');
                        $("#phototable").append(row);
                    } else {
                        var row = $("#thumbnailsrow" + rownumber);
                    }
                    //images[arraycount++]'<td><a href=' + imagelink + '><img src=' + thumbnaillink + '/></a></td>')
                    var curid="imgload"+downloadcounter;
                    //$("#loadimg").append("<div id="+curid+"></div>");
                    //$("#loadimg").append("<img src="+thumbnaillink+"></img>");
                    //$("#"+curid).hide();
                    //$("#"+curid).load(thumbnaillink);
                    $(row).append('<td align=center><a href=' + imagelink + '><img src=' + thumbnaillink + '/></a></td>');
                    //$("#"+curid).remove();
                    downloadcounter+=1;
                    totalimagecount+=1;
                    if(totalimagecount==uploadedfiles.length){
                        $("#loading").hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    if(toolarge != "") {
        alert("These images were not uploaded due to size limit of 1MB\n" + toolarge);
    }
}
```

Comment: if your loading img is set to show over images it will get shown every request so will seem like it never gets hiden

Comment: I want the images added by this line to show,

$(row).append('<td align=center><a href=' + imagelink + '><img src=' + thumbnaillink + '/></a></td>')

Comment: Don't post the solution in your question, add it as a response and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want separate responses, you have to make separate requests.

Don't asynchronously fire 100 requests at once though, just fire X and hold a counter that you check with a timer. Each time you receive a response you decrease that counter and each time the timer hits you can simply fire `X - counter` requests. That way you only have X simultaneous requests at a time...

Comment: I am making separate requests and getting separate responses as well. The problem is I cant reflect the response in the HTML using the usual way. Thanks for your tips about not overloading the server with async requests though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `The problem is I cant reflect the response in the HTML using the usual way`?

Comment: What I mean is, say I send request 1, and receive response 1, the thumbnail link is in response 1, I am adding the thumbnail link to the html using,
 $(row).append('<td align=center><a href=' + imagelink + '><img src=' + thumbnaillink + '/></a></td>')
 This should show the thumbnail immediately in html page but it does not. It shows up all right only after all the responses have been received.  I have written in my update that this works perfectly if image placeholder is added before the requests are made.

Comment: @specialscope: Interesting, can you check with FireBug or some other inspector in the Net(work) tab when you get the responses back? That is, for an individual request/response you see how long the horizontal bar is. It could be that it's actually somehow delaying any response to your browser until all files were uploaded. Thought about otherwise, it could be that requests get precedence over responses...

Comment: Tom, thanks I will have a look and will let you know the results.

Comment: Hi, it appears that during ajax process the browser is too busy to do any dom update. Surprisingly it does text updates such as my image counter but not image itself. But I used the idea you suggested and used setTimeout(ajax,timeouttime), the update went quite smoothly.

Comment: @specialscope: The `V` mark in front of an answer is to remark the answer as the solution and to mark your question as solved, don't add something in front of the title as that leads to inconsistency. Glad to have helped you and thank you for updating us about your fix... :)

Comment: could you update your answer to reflect the need to use setTimeout function for making sequential multiple ajax call if dynamic update is required. I could then mark your answer as accepted solution. There is no need to add another reply I think.